# How do you say someone writes a lot of unnecessary words?

Tags: word-request, antonyms

Let's say that you read a book or a newspaper and you find that the writer writes too much unnecessary information. Is there a word to describe that? Also is there a word that describes exactly the opposite situation?

Comment: Extraneous, superfluous, verbose, wordy... concise, erudite, prosaic

Comment: **redundant** may be the word when the information provided is unnecessary and the meaning is clear.

Comment: @lurker - "erudite"?  Buh?  "Erudite" means "having or showing knowledge that is learned by studying".  Ditto for "prosaic" - it means "dull or ordinary". Another, fancier possibility is [prolix](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prolix): "using an excess of words".  Opposites might be [terse](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/terse), or [brief](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brief), or [succinct](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/succinct).

Comment: They are not irreconcilable. Erudite and Prosaic *skip the fluff*.

Comment: 'Long-winded' or one of many synonyms in a [thesaurus](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english-thesaurus/long-winded). For the opposite, see antonyms in the same thesaurus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are numerous adjectives that can be used (like *wordy*, *redundant*, or *extraneous*), but I'll focus on one that might be of interest to the English learner: ***flowery language***.

King and Sanders have compiled a book entitled *15 Blunders: Common Errors Writers Often Make*, and the title of Chapter 1 is "Avoid Flowery Language." A sentence in the opening chapter exhorts readers: "Say what you want to say in simple language." Another [website](http://www.digitalhistory.uh.edu/references/writing_guides/grammar.cfm) gives eight tips for effective writing, and says, "avoid flowery language and delete needless words."

Wordnik defines *flowery* as:

> Of a speech or piece of writing: too complicated; elaborate; with grandiloquent expressions; bombastic; verbose

A word that can describe the opposite is *pithy*, which [means](https://www.wordnik.com/words/pithy):

> Precisely meaningful; forceful and brief

It should be noted, though: *flowery language* is a common and recognizable phrase, but the word *pithy* is not so well-known and it's not in widespread use.